# Modify the spoiler

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a cod http://jsfiddle.net/VWCnd/8/. How do the following: when the presses "open all" all + changed to - ?

html:

```
<a onclick=$("div[class^='spoiler_toggle']").show() style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration: underline;">expand all</a>
        /
<a onclick=$("div[class^='spoiler_toggle']").hide() style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration: underline;">close all</a>

<a href="" class="spoiler_title">Title<span class="sp_ind">+</span></a>

<div class="spoiler_toggle">
    <div class="spoiler_bg">
        <p>
artile
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.spoiler_title {
    display:block;
    background-color: #551A8B;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
.spoiler_toggle {
    display:none;
}
.sp_ind{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.spoiler_bg {
    background: #9C6AC9;
    padding: 1px 10px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.spoiler_title').click(function(){
     $(this).find(".sp_ind").text(($(this).find(".sp_ind").text() == '+' ? '-' : '+'))
  $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_toggle').toggle();
  return false;
 });
});
```

Thank you guys for helping noobs :)

Comment: I looked at the fiddle and I'm not seeing what's going on here, or what you're asking. Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: When you press open all minus is minus and the need to changed by plus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to HTML:

```
<a class="expander" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration: underline;">expand all</a>
    /
<a class="collapser" style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration: underline;">close all</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".expander").click(function(){
    $("div[class^='spoiler_toggle']").show();
    $(".spoiler_title .sp_ind").text('-');
  });    

  $(".collapser").click(function(){
    $("div[class^='spoiler_toggle']").hide();
    $(".spoiler_title .sp_ind").text('+');
  });    

  $('.spoiler_title').click(function(){
    $(this).find(".sp_ind").text(($(this).find(".sp_ind").text() == '+' ? '-' : '+'))
    $(this).parent().children('div.spoiler_toggle').toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback function of `.text()` to set the + or - :

```
$(this).find(".sp_ind").text(function() {
     return $(this).text() == "+" ? "-" : "+";
});
```

Per @ScottSauyet's comment, here's an updated demo updating your link text as well: http://jsfiddle.net/VWCnd/16/

Comment: But that means that clicking "expand all" when it's already expanded acts like "close all".  I assume that's not what's required.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Most likely not, the expand all / close all should just be on toggler that changes the text similar to this function.

Comment: @ScottSauyet -- Included a demo updating link text as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use JQuery, I suggest you restructure your code a bit, first of all clean your markup to something like:

```
<a href="#" id="expand_all">expand all</a>
        /
<a href="#" id="close_all">close all</a>
<a href="" class="spoiler_title">Title<span class="sp_ind">+</span></a>

<div class="spoiler_toggle">
    <div class="spoiler_bg">
        <p>artile</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is how your jquery might look like:

```
$('.spoiler_title').on("click", function(e){
    toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#expand_all").on("click", function(e) {
    expand();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#close_all").on("click", function(e) {
    colapse();
    e.preventDefault();
});

var colapse = function() {
    var spoilerToggle = $(".spoiler_toggle");
    if(spoilerToggle.is(":visible")) {
        spoilerToggle.hide();
    }        
    $(".sp_ind").text("+");
};

var expand = function() {
    var spoilerToggle = $(".spoiler_toggle");
    if(!spoilerToggle.is(":visible")) {
        spoilerToggle.show();
    }     
    $(".sp_ind").text("-");
};

var toggle = function() {
    var toggleButton = $(".sp_ind");
    $(".spoiler_toggle").toggle();
    var text = toggleButton.text() === "+" ? "-" : "+";
    toggleButton.text(text);
};
```

Here is your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VWCnd/15/

Answer (score 0):

Here's **[an approach](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/aWaCs/)** that might suit:

```
<a onclick="changeState('show')" ...>expand all</a>
<a onclick="changeState('hide')" ...>close all</a>

var changeState = (function() {
    var showing = false;
    return function(type) {
        if (type !== 'show' && type !== 'hide') { // 'toggle' or other
            type = showing ? 'hide' : 'show';
        }
        showing = (type === 'show');
        $("div[class^='spoiler_toggle']")[type]();
        $(".sp_ind").text(type === 'show' ? '-' : '+');
        return false;
    }
}());

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.spoiler_title').click(function() {
        return changeState('toggle');
    });
});
```

I would suggest moving this inline handlers into the document ready block as well, but that's left as an exercise.  (It would also allow you to move the changeState function inside and stop polluting the global scope.)